# Does listener service require Oracle server to be installed?

Tags: windows-7, listener, oracle8i

I have installed Oracle 8i Client version in my machine. I have created local service naming to. I am trying to connect the local service. I am getting below error,

```
The test did not succeed.
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

There may be an error in the fields entered,
or the server may not be ready for a connection.
```

Do I need server to be installed in my machine for the listener to be run in my machine?

Comment: Using Net8 Assistant I added Service Naming, with protocol TCP/IP and with my server details and Port 1521.When trying to test the service I got below error "The test did not succeed. ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

There may be an error in the fields entered, or the server may not be ready for a connection."

Answer (score 1):

- Where is the database server running?
- Did you create a listener on the local machine?  If so, please post the listener.ora in addition to the tnsnames.ora file.

Normally, the listener would run on the database server.  It is possible to run the listener on a machine other than the database server but that would not be a particularly common configuration.  It would be much more common to run the database and the listener on your laptop.

It would be extremely unusual, though, to want to install any version of 8i today.  8.1.7 has been desupported for nearly a decade and isn't supported on any operating system that is vaguely near supported.

Comment: Using Net8 Assistant I added Service Naming, with protocol TCP/IP and with my server details and Port 1521.When trying to test the service I got below error "The test did not succeed. ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

There may be an error in the fields entered, or the server may not be ready for a connection."

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - It sounds like you created a local TNS alias, not a listener.  When you were filling in the details, those details would be for the listener running on the remote server.  Are you certain those connection details are correct?  What operating system are you using on the client and the server?  What version of the database?  What version of the listener?

Comment: Yes I created TNS alias. the details are correct. The client machine which I am using is Windows 7. I don't have info about the server machine. I have installed Oracle 8i client. Is there any way to check the server machine is  running and the version details of server ?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - You can ping it.  But you are undoubtedly not pinging it on the port the listener is running on.  Are you sure the listener is running on the remote server on the port you specified when you created the local TNS alias?

Comment: I am not sure. Is there any way to check the listener is running or not?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - If you can log on to the remote server, you can use the command `lsnrctl status`.  Or you can look at the listener.ora file on the remote server.  If you can successfully connect from other client machines, you can check the TNS alias on those machines.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Before going to the Server, is there any way to test this from client itself?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - Can you connect from another client machine?  You could also try telnetting to the remote server from the client machine on the port you specified in the TNS alias though that will generally only tell you that something is running on that particular port not necessarily that there is an Oracle listener running on that port.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the listener is part of the server, not the client. As you're trying to connect to a locally installed server (I guess) and that server doesn't exist (as you installed only the client) the client will respond that there is no listener (as the listener would be what's replying to the client, not the server directly).